# Adding background colour to a button when clicked stays in that state until the next button clicked in that button group in vue js 2

Tags: vuejs2, element-ui

I have two button groups which are created from arrays by using v-for directive in Vue Js. When I clicked a button in first button group I need it to be in focused until the other button click in that button group, the focus state does not affected by any other click events, except the other button was clicked in that button group. The buttons are 1.All 2. True, 3. False, 4. None In the initial stage 1.All button has to be focused until the next button clicked in that button group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of the active button by adding an active property to each array element:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'All',
        active: true
      },
      {
        text: 'True',
        active: false
      },
      {
        text: 'False',
        active: false
      },
      {
        text: 'None',
        active: false
      }
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    activate (b) {
      this.buttons.forEach(button => {
        button.active = button.text === b.text
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```css
button {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button v-for="(b,i) in buttons" :key="i" type="button" :style="{ 'background-color': b.active ? 'green' : 'grey' }" @click="activate(b)">{{ b.text }}</button>
</div>
```